# How to format the request uri for a Vimeo unlisted private video

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to get private vimeo video details, here is the video: https://vimeo.com/304887422/34c51f7a09

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#get_video

When I test here and enter video url ( 304887422/34c51f7a09 ), it just strips forward slash.

How can I get these video details with api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an unlisted private video with URL format `https://vimeo.com/[video_id]/[hash]` you'll need to append the hash to the end of the video_id with a colon, see here:

```
https://api.vimeo.com/videos/[video_id]:[hash]
```

For your example, the video request would look like this:

```
https://api.vimeo.com/videos/304887422:34c51f7a09
```

Comment: Is there any documentation for this in more details? Is this the same format for all private videos?

Comment: This is the same format for all *unlisted* private videos. Unlisted private videos are the only type of private videos that require the additional hash in the request uri - other videos can be accessed using the standard `/videos/[video_id]` uri format.

Comment: Do private videos in channel or album for example have uri with the same format? 304887422:34c51f7a09